# How to Bind Enum with a radio Button in Blend ?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, data-binding, expression-blend

I have two projects in my solution. One is WPF and another one is ClassLibrary. In my Class Library project I have an Enum and I bound it to my View in WPF project as Static Resources.

My Code Is :

```
namespace DPOS.Core.Helpers
{
   public enum SearchOptions
   {
       SingleDate,
       DateRange,
       Name,
       Amount,
       Quantity,
       All
   }
}

xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:DPOS.Core.Helpers;assembly=DPOS.Core"


RadioButton x:Name="RadioSingleDate" Content="{Binding SingleDateContent}" 
Margin="0,21.54,0,0" TabIndex="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource RadioButtonStyle}"
IsChecked="{Binding SearchOptions, ConverterParameter={x:Static helpers:SearchOptions.SingleDate}, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}}"/>
```

This work`s file in Visual Studio 2012.
But Problem is when I Open it in Blend (Blend for Visual studio) then it say :

**The name "SearchOptions" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:DPOS.Core.Helpers;assembly=DPOS.Core"**

I don`t understand what is happening.

Am I Missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I slove my problem by Re adding my ClassLibrary project reference using blend.